# Trying to grep url with random ending

Tags: linux, url, grep

Url always ends with 8 random characters.
I can easily grep https://websitef.com/ with

grep https://websitef.com/ test.txt

but cant figure out how to get those 8 random characters that come after

This is what it looks like in file:

```
..."num_comments": 16, "url": "https://websitef.com/vkl6owav", "_has_fetched": true.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is JSON, you may want to consider using a JSON-specific tool.

Let' consider your test file:

```
$ cat file
..."num_comments": 16, "url": "https://websitef.com/vkl6owav", "_has_fetched": true.....
```

To grep the string that you want:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=https://websitef.com/)\w+' file
vkl6owav
```

`\w+` matches a string of word characters.  `(?<=https://websitef.com/)` is a look-behind that restricts the match to characters that follow the string `https://websitef.com/`.  This requires GNU grep.

If GNU grep is not available, `sed` can be used:

```
$ sed -En 's|.*https://websitef.com/([[:alnum:]]+).*|\1|p' file
vkl6owav
```

If you wanted the whole URL, not just the random string:

```
$ grep -o 'https://websitef.com/[[:alnum:]]*' file
https://websitef.com/vkl6owav
```

Comment: Yes it is JSON file. I might not have asked the question in best way, i want to extract multiple of these links from multiple files. Where only constant is              https://websitef.com/         and the 8 charachters after it change.

Comment: @Janice9000 In that case, the last solution should work for you.